# What reference system uses coordinates such as "726822 4881333 to grid reference 726803 4881420"? (Nova Scotia Anglers' Handbook, 2021)

Tags: coordinates

Here is a sample from the Handbook.  I don't know how I am supposed to fish legally here when I don't have a clue where and where not!

> DIGBY COUNTY
> Salmon River, downstream from the Route 1 Highway Bridge approximately 500 m to a line drawn across the Salmon River from grid reference 726822 4881333 to grid reference 726803 4881420, including tributaries,May 1 to Dec 31.

How does this translate to GPS, decimal or degrees?

Comment: Thank you so much!  It's been quite an education for this aging mind today.  It all worked out.  I was a teacher all my life, and just saw how complicated the world of Geography can be.

Comment: Link to the Angler's guide is https://beta.novascotia.ca/sites/default/files/documents/1-2412/anglers-handbook-en.pdf

Answer (score 1):

They're UTM grid references on a topographic map, but in most cases the guide doesn't tell you which map.  That guide is poorly written in that respect.  It probably assumes that you know.

If you can figure out which UTM zone you are in, you can plug the grid reference into most GPS as-is or if you need latitude, longitude you can use any online converter.

For the grid ref. you provided, I tried UTM Zone 19, 20 & 21

[image]

And entered 726822 4881333 into some [random converter](http://rcn.montana.edu/Resources/Converter.aspx) I found via google. I used North American 27 as the datum because of the note on page 10:

> The Datum type used for grid references to identify boundaries for specific fishing areas is NAD 27

And got these coordinates for Zone 19 (nearly all of Nova Scotia is in Zone 20 so I tried that first, but it wasn't right):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It's been quite an education for this aging mind today. It all worked out. I was a teacher all my life, and just saw how complicated the world of Geography can be.

Comment: Some of the coordinates *are* Zone 20 though! p32: "grid reference 583545 5054009 at Williams Point " - put into the convertor for Zone 20 and it's dead on Williams Point....

Comment: @Spacedman, yes I'm aware of that. The guide covers all of Nova Scotia which is mostly in 20, with western and eastern parts in 19 and 21.